# Functional Programming in Javascript return values

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm currently going through the book "Functional Programming" by Michael Fogus. I have two questions that I have been unable to answer through my own research.

I haven't seen this convention before :

```
function truthy(x) { return (x !== false) && existy(x) }
```

where existy is :

```
function existy(x) { return x != null }
```

I haven't seen the use of && when returning something. What is its purpose?

Another example of that later in the book is :

```
function plucker(field) {
   return function(obj) {
      return (obj && obj[field])
   }
}
```

In that example, if I replace `obj && obj[field]` with just `obj[field]` it returns the same thing. What is the point of writing it the way he did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an `AND` operation, we know that if one of the operand of the expression is `false` then the expression is `false` for sure.

Some Programming Languages make use of this laziness and do not call second operand if the first operand is `false` because it is a fact that the result is definitely `false`.

For example, in PHP, there is a very common usage:

```
connect() || die('Error');
```

if `connect` function returns `true` then there is no need to evaluate second operand since the result is `true` for sure. Because of that, `die` is never called.

---

In your `plucker` case, if `obj` is null then, it does not try to reach `obj[field]` because the result is already set as `false` (false && anything = false) and no need to evaluate it.

However, if `obj` is not null (true), then in order to calculate the return result, the second operand must be evaluated, which is `obj[field]`. So for this example, if `obj[field]` is not null then it returns `true`, otherwise returns `false`.

the return statement of `plucker` example can also be written as:

```
if (obj != null)
    return obj[field];
return false;
```

Comment: In this example then, if it reaches obj[field] then that is what is returned correct?

Comment: if `obj` is not null then the expression can be shrinken as `return obj[field]`.

Comment: Okay I think I get it now. If I could upvote both of the answers in this thread I would.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially returning `((x !== false) && existy(x))`, which results in a boolean.

Maybe this example will make it more clear:

```
var number1 = 10;
var number2 = 20;

if(number1 === 10 && number2 === 20) { 
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Is essentially the same as:

```
var number = 3;

return number1 === 10 && number2 === 20;
```

As for your the second part of your question, why the result is the same when you remove the `obj &&` part from the statement:

This is because `obj` existsts and `obj[field]` exists too. If you'd try to check if something **inside of** an object (`obj`) exists, you'd get an error if it does not. Therefor , it's neccessary to check if the object exists first and then if the property inside of it exists.

So you want to ask your code:

> Does *object* exist AND IF SO does *parameter in object* exist?

Which translates to:

```
obj && obj[field]
```

Comment: I know it returns a boolean. I wasn't sure of why the && was needed in the return statement. That's why I included another example of it.